# Not able to render pages through router link in angular as expected

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Below is the code for the dashboard, When I am clicking on the links on my dashboard, it changes the url in the browser but does not render the new page and instead dashboard remains.

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**admin-layout.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from '../../user-profile/user-profile.component';

import { NotificationsComponent } from '../../notifications/notifications.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../../about/about.component';
import { CatalogComponent } from '../../pxsbaas-catalog/pxsdbaas-catalog.component';
import { FormComponent } from '../../pxsbaas-catalog/standalone-form/standalone-form.component'

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent ,
        children: [
                    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
                    {path: 'pbxbaasCatalog', component: CatalogComponent,
                        children: [
                                    {path: 'Form', component: FormComponent }
                                  ]
                    },
                  ],
    },
    { path: 'user-profile',   component: UserProfileComponent },
    { path: 'notifications',  component: NotificationsComponent }
];
```

Below is the HTML of dashboard component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Form']">
      <div class="card-header card-header-icon">
          <h4 class="card-title">request form</h4>
      </div>
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['about']">
      <div class="card-header card-header-icon">
          <h4 class="card-title">go to about page</h4>
      </div>
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['pbxbaasCatalog']">
      <div class="card-header card-header-icon">
          <h4 class="card-title">go to catalog page</h4>
      </div>
</a>
```

In the above html , when I click on the router links in browser it changes the url as /dashboard/about or /dashboard/Form or /dashboard/pbxbaasCatalog but does not render the html page of their respectove components

Comment: Does it through any error?

Comment: No it does not throw any error, In the below case when clicked on about, url in the browser changes to http://localhost:4200/dashboard/about but I still see the dashboard page.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's going on, try without `children`, by creating new routes such as `{ path: 'dashboard/about' ...}`

Comment: So I am not sure what the reason is...                                                       
    { path: 'dashboard/about', component: AboutComponent}, --> does not works for http://localhost:4200/dashboard/about , but 
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}, --> works for http://localhost:4200/about

Comment: To make sure you know this, you are supposed to use `children` only when your component (here it is DashboardComponent) has a RouterOutlet.